# Is there a good way to preserve comments while modifying clojure code?

Tags: clojure, edn

I am reading a clojure source code file using clojure's  read-string.
However single line comments are naturally ignored by the reader. When I generate new source code, those comments are no there anymore.

Is there a way I can preserve these comments ?

Comment: Could you add more details about what specifically you're doing and why your task requires the use of code parsing and generation?

Comment: There a lot of files in the source code, around 100 that have been written using some library and we are moving to an alternative. I have done most of automation needed. I read forms modify and generate new ones.

Comment: But even ignoring the problem of comments, won't you still lose *a lot* of information about the actual structure of the original source code? Formatting is one example, but try this: ``(map (comp pr-str read-string) ["2r101010" "::rect" "{:a 1 :b 2}" "#{:a :b :c}" "'form" "\\u03A9" "@form" "^{:a 1 :b 2} [1 2 3]" "#'x" "#()" "`(fred x ~x lst ~@lst 7 8 :nine)'"])``

Comment: We are managing with pretty print. Moving from Midje to clojure test.

Comment: `pprint` still doesn't work: ``(run! (comp clojure.pprint/pprint read-string) ["2r101010" "::rect" "{:a 1 :b 2}" "#{:a :b :c}" "\\u03A9" "^{:a 1 :b 2} [1 2 3]" "#()" "`(fred x ~x lst ~@lst 7 8 :nine)"])``

Comment: @SamEstep We have a simple use case and things are working out for us. Do you have a solution for getting comments, if not then what's point in rendering what we are doing as baseless. Its like saying "I can't bring the life jacket, but why did you enter the river?".

Comment: My point is that you have not provided enough information about the problem you're trying to solve. Until you address the elephant in the room of all the *other* problems with your current approach (besides the one problem that you stated in your question), it's hard for us to provide useful advice. You need to add a much more detailed description of the code you're transforming, why it doesn't suffer from all the problems that I raised, how you're currently doing the transformation, and how you'd *like* to be able to do the transformation, preferably with actual code and examples.

Comment: @SamEstep I got your point. Sorry for being a bit rude. rewrite-clj looks interesting will look into it.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to find a solution to your problem! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rewrite-clj https://github.com/xsc/rewrite-clj seems perfect for what you are trying to do? It preserves comments.